# PIG Filter by latest year

Tags: hadoop, foreach, filter, apache-pig

How do I filter a data that only takes up the most recently updated information? Here's the sample data.

Data:

```
United States of America    2000    Dentistry personnel density 162.7
United States of America    2000    Health management & support workers 1237.9
United States of America    2000    Laboratory health workers   228.4
United States of America    1995    Nursing and midwifery personnel 879.80005
United States of America    2000    Nursing and midwifery personnel 936.69995
United States of America    2005    Nursing and midwifery personnel 981.49994
United States of America    1995    Other health workers    650.89996
United States of America    2000    Other health workers    1452.1
United States of America    2005    Other health workers    494.3
United States of America    2009    Other health workers    849.89996
United States of America    2010    Other health workers    857.9
United States of America    2011    Other health workers    845.89996
United States of America    2000    Pharmaceutical personnel    87.6
United States of America    2010    Pharmaceutical personnel    88.1
United States of America    1995    Physicians  239.5
United States of America    2000    Physicians  256.4
United States of America    2004    Physicians  267.19998
United States of America    2005    Physicians  240.9
United States of America    2006    Physicians  240.2
United States of America    2007    Physicians  241.00002
United States of America    2008    Physicians  241.59999
United States of America    2009    Physicians  242.2
United States of America    2010    Physicians  241.00002
United States of America    2011    Physicians  245.2
Uruguay 2002    Dentistry personnel density 116.1
Uruguay 2008    Dentistry personnel density 70.1
Uruguay 2008    Health management & support workers 69.5
Uruguay 2008    Laboratory health workers   17.0
Uruguay 2002    Nursing and midwifery personnel 84.899994
Uruguay 2008    Nursing and midwifery personnel 554.8
Uruguay 2008    Other health workers    137.0
Uruguay 2008    Pharmaceutical personnel    53.100002
Uruguay 2002    Physicians  365.19998
Uruguay 2008    Physicians  373.6
```

What I want:

```
United States of America    2000    Dentistry personnel density 162.7
United States of America    2000    Health management & support workers 1237.9
United States of America    2000    Laboratory health workers   228.4
United States of America    2005    Nursing and midwifery personnel 981.49994
United States of America    2011    Other health workers    845.89996
United States of America    2010    Pharmaceutical personnel    88.1
United States of America    2011    Physicians  245.2
Uruguay 2008    Dentistry personnel density 70.1
Uruguay 2008    Health management & support workers 69.5
Uruguay 2008    Laboratory health workers   17.0
Uruguay 2008    Nursing and midwifery personnel 554.8
Uruguay 2008    Other health workers    137.0
Uruguay 2008    Pharmaceutical personnel    53.100002
Uruguay 2008    Physicians  373.6
```

I want to make sure if the country and the career is the same, I only filter by the latest year it was given.

Here's my code, but it's not working.

```
b = LOAD '/nomnom' AS (country:chararray, year:int, career:chararray, density:chararray);

c = GROUP b by (country,career);

d = FOREACH c GENERATE MAX(b.year) AS val, group, $1 as max;

e = FOREACH d {
row = FILTER b BY (year == val);
GENERATE FLATTEN(row);
};

DUMP e;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you grouped (`c`), sort the grouped data by year and take the latest one:

```
d = foreach c {
  sorted = order b by year desc;
  latest = limit sorted 1;
  generate FLATTEN(latest);
}
dump d;
```